# Merge two strings in a line where | delimiter

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I want to merge two strings in a line with `|` as the delimiter. We can combine by using `awk '{$1,$2,$3$4$5}'`, is there any other way to merge the string using `|` as the delimiter?

Input:

```
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag | yuiji
```

output:

```
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|yuiji
```

Comment: Do you have further examples of your input data that you could share? Do you always have two `|`-delimited fields per record? Are all `|` always occurring with a single space around them? Does any field contain embedded `|` characters or newlines?

Comment: Nope ,they are more records with " | " as delimiter. I just use sed to replace them....thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data contains fields separated by `|`, and that the delimiting `|` characters may possibly contain spaces on either side.  Then the input field separator you would use with `awk` is the expression  `*[|] *`, i.e. an expression matching the `|` character and any flanking spaces.

Using the single character `|` as the output field separator and forcing `awk` to re-create the records for output (by setting one of the fields) would then solve your issue, at least in the way that you have presented it in your question.

```bsh
awk -F ' *[|] *' -v OFS='|' '{ $1=$1 }; 1' file
```

or, equivalently,

```bsh
awk -F ' *[|] *' -v OFS='|' '{ $1=$1; print }' file
```

Testing this:

```
$ cat file
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag | yuiji
```

```
$ awk -F ' *[|] *' -v OFS='|' '{ $1=$1 }; 1' file
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|yuiji
```

You could also use a substitution in `sed` with a similar expression:

```
$ sed 's/ *| */|/g' file
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|yuiji
```

This is all assuming we may treat the data as text or as "simple" CSV data, with no delimiters, newlines, or quotes embedded in quoted fields.

Answer (score 0):

given input data,

```
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag | one
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag     |     two
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|third
```

## default separator

either use default `awk` separator (one or more consecutive space or tab),

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3$4$5}' v
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|one
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|two
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|third
```

note that 3th field change

```
awk '{printf "3th:[%s]\n",$3}' v
3th:[Xxyxhsag]
3th:[Xxyxhsag]
3th:[Xxyxhsag|third]
```

This may be a solution if you always have 5 field in you real case.

## pipe (|) separator

you cab use `|` as separator, but this will keep space in fields

```
awk -F\| '{printf "%s|%s\n", $1, $2}' v
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag | one
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag     |     two
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|third
```

this might be more explicit if I change output separator to `!`

```
awk -F\| '{printf "%s!%s\n", $1, $2}' v
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag ! one
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag     !     two
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag!third
```

Now, you don't have too much gain as you have to strip trailling space from `$1` and leading from `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

with `awk` you can try:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/ \| /,"|")} 1' file
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag|yuiji
```

- we set FS and OFS (same value: `|`)
- only with this we have this result:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '1' file
XXXXXXXX 0 Xxyxhsag | yuiji
```

- so we remove the spaces left and right of `|` using `sub()`:

```
{sub(/ \| /,"|")}
```